# How to override implemtation of certain method of protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

I have a class `ClassA` which defines `protocol A` which inherits from `protocol B`.

```
@protocol protocolA <protocolB>

-(void)anAddedMethodToTheInheritiedMethod;
@end

@interface ClassA
@property (nonatomic,weak) id <protocolA> myDelegate;
@end
```

In another class ("MyClass") I receive an object which complies to protocol A.

```
@interface MyClass
@property (nonatomic,weak) id <protocolA> myDelegate;
@end
```

in the implementation of MyClass I create an object of type ClassA

```
@implementation MyClass

-(void)someMethod
{
  self.myObjectOfTypeA = [ClassA new];
  self.myObjectOfTypeA.delegate = self.myDelegate;
}
@end
```

Of course this is a bug because self.myDelegate doesn't respond to

> "anAddedMethodToTheInheritiedMethod".

In order to solve this I could set MyClass object as the delegate to ClassA , stub out all of the delegated methods, call self.myDelegate to the methods that it answers, and answer the "added" delegate methods from ClassA.

But this is a lot of boiler plate code, and prone to breakage if the original protocol changes. I'm sure there is a cleaner way to achieve this.

How can this be done?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve? If you want `myObjectOfTypeA` to act as a proxy there are better ways to do it. If you are trying to do something like the contravariance supported in other languages.

Comment: Its more a Proxy as you suggest. There is "layering" of protocols, and who should answer what (which classes). I don't necessarily want to override the delegate method implementation in the "container" class, only certain methods of the delegate (such as those which pertain to view, not data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is a class that acts as a proxy for several other classes which implement various protocols. This 'dispatcher' class would receive messages and send them on to the instances that actually handle them, similar to a proxy (just with multiple targets hidden behind it). If that is the case, use [message forwarding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html) to reduce the amount of boilerplate code - instead of having to implement every protocol method, just implement the message forwarding methods and decide which objects to forward the messages to. If your protocols change over time you won't have to constantly add methods to your dispatcher class, as the forwarding mechanism will take care of that. For even more detail on the subject, I highly recommend [Mike Ash](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-03-27-objective-c-message-forwarding.html).